# How to JOIN tow or more @ManyToMany fiels in @Query in JPA

Tags: jpa, join, many-to-many, inner-join

I have:

```
public class Foo {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Bar> bars;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Baz> bazs;

    @Column(name = "text_data")
    private String txt;

}
```

then I have:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityPermission,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT f.txt FROM Foo f JOIN f.bars bars <...> ")
    Set<String> getFooTxts(@Param("bar") Bar bar, @Param("baz") Baz baz);

}
```

**Question is:**
   What I should put instead: **<...>** to get all **Foo.txt** from all Foo rows which are connected to specified **Bar bar** and **Baz baz** ?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about something like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT f.txt 
    FROM Foo f JOIN f.bars bars 
    WHERE bars.id = :bar.id 
    AND f.id IN ( 
        SELECT f2.id 
        FROM Foo f2 JOIN f2.bazs bazs 
        WHERE bazs.id = :baz.id )")
```

but it looks not nice and not sure if it will be working :(

// edit

it is not working

got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Validation failed for query for method public abstract ...
```

// edit

looks like

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT f.txt 
    FROM Foo f JOIN f.bars bars JOIN f.bazs bazs 
    WHERE bars = :bar 
    AND bazs = :baz ")
```

this query was successfully initialized - but I am not sure if it work correctly